# How to fetch claims from the request in the .NET WebAPI if the authentication/authorization is at API gateway level (Kong)?

Tags: jwt, microservices, api-gateway, kong

We have

1. Identity server which generates JWT tokens along with custom claims based on the username and password.
2. Order microservice with the endpoint "/orders" which returns the list of orders based on the claims present in the present JWT token.
3. Kong gateway to handle all the requests and forward to appropriate service based on configuration.
4. We have enabled JWT plugin in Kong to authorized requests (i.e validate the JWT token generated by the Identity server).

What is the best way to get the claims in the Order microservice if we have not written any logic related to authentication and authorization in the Startup class?

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: We have used the "JWT2Header" plugin of the Kong which converts the JWT Claims into Headers before sending requests to upstream. Then we have to fetch claims values from the Headers in our service.